# How to uninstall Ubuntu 20.04 and install Windows 10. Single-Boot

Tags: 20.04, windows-10

I have searched for this question in the forum but something is not clear to me. They say that if I have Single-Boot I only have to install Windows on the partition where Ubuntu is installed and the installer will do the rest. Is that correct? If so then my question is: How do I know which partition Ubuntu is installed on? I don't have much knowledge of Ubuntu so please be detailed with the answer so I can understand it. Thanks

Comment: Windows will not install to a Linux formatted partition. Not sure if it has a similar to Ubuntu choice of totally erase drive and install. In UEFI mode it wants lots of partitions and has to have gpt partitioning, so best to just let Windows install. Be sure to boot its installer in UEFI boot mode. If in Ubuntu you can see partitions with: `lsblk -f`. Any Windows questions then should be on a Windows forum or other StackExchange site as this is an Ubuntu only question & answer site.

Comment: No, you don't reuse any Ubuntu partition for Windows. And it really doesn't matter if there's an OS, any OS, already installed when installing a new one. We simply remove all partitions and let the installer automatically create all the needed partitions. The problem here is not  insufficient knowledge about Ubuntu but about installing OSes.

Comment: You don't uninstall an OS you don't want, you just install over it.

Answer (score 0):

we need ntfs format partition to get the windows installed.

As you have mentioned that many suggested you can only make single boot.
i.e if you install ubuntu with single boot the total file system will be in ext2,ext3,fat ... but not ntfs, So you can't seperate the partition,

if windows installation need to be done, the file system should be changed,So linux changes will be over written(need to be formatted).